# Missing code coverage for closing brace after code throwing an exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, code-coverage, xunit

In Visual Studio 2017 a closing brace after a statement that is throwing an exception is considered uncovered.

In my case I have a test checking if a NullReferenceException is thrown:

```
[Fact]
public void PassingNullConsoleWriter_ThrowsArgumentNullException()
{
    Assert.Throws<ArgumentNullException>(() => new UsagePrinter(null));
}
```

Analyzing code coverage in this form of the code marks the whole body of the lambda as uncovered, what obviously is not true:

[image: Code Coverage marks body of lambda uncovered]

Expanding the lambda to a statement lambda uncovers that actually it is the closing brace after the statement throwing the exception that is considered uncovered:

[image: Code Coverage marks the closing brace uncovered]

Note that the overall coverage of the file in both cases is the same.

Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: you shouldn't be running code coverage on tests, you run code coverage on the code that the tests run against.

Comment: All your test assemblies would likely benefit from `[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]`

Comment: @Kritner, thank you for your comment. Sure, I can (and probably will) do that. But I'd like to cover the test assemblies to reveal unused testing infrastructure code.

Comment: Checking code coverage on tests is helpful to identify sections of the test that are not running as expected.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
[Fact]
public void PassingNullConsoleWriter_ThrowsArgumentNullException()
{
    var exception = Record.Exception(() => new UsagePrinter(null));
    Assert.IsType<ArgumentNullException>(exception);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the result is basically the same. The closing brace is considered uncovered. So, I will take one of the other routes you described.